# What's the output of this code and why?

Tags: c, gcc, comments

With the following code, what's the output of this code, and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("Hello world\n"); // \\
        printf("What's the meaning of this?");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile with a C89 compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The backslash at the end of the 4th line is escaping the following new line so that they become one continuous line. And because we can see the // beginning a comment, the 5th line is commented out.

That is, your code is the equivalent of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("Hello world\n"); // \printf("What's the meaning of this?");
        return 0;
}
```

The output is simply "Hello world" with a new line.

**Edit:** As Erik and pmg both said, this is true in C99 but not C89. Credit where credit is due.

It is defined in the 2nd phase of translation (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §5.1.1.2):

> Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line
>   character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

Answer (score 2):

It's "Hello world\n". Didn't you try? Line continuation (and e.g trigraphs) are well documented, look it up. A syntax highlighting editor (e.g. Visual Studio with VA X) will make this obvious.

Note that this works in C99 and C++ - *not* C89

Comment: That's what i was thinking on, but the editor that i'm using (xcode and nano) don't do the highlighting, was thinking that was something else... will try with another text editor.

Comment: @user688379: As other answers say, it's simply line continuation due to the final backslash

Comment: @user688379: Also, as a side note, if this is from some book, ditch it, it's not teaching you C but C tricks.

Comment: Not a book, something that happened in our job, our editor didn't highlighted the comment, with one backslash (\) it highlights, but more it doesn't.

Comment: @user688379: gcc with -Wall gives a warning, so does MSVC. Yet another point in favor of making your build warning-free at strictest level :)

Comment: I wouldn't rely too heavily on editors getting this right - their syntax coloring parsers often aren't particularly sophisticated. Visual Studio, Eclipse and SlickEdit seem to get this right, other editors I've taken a look at don't.

Answer (score 1):

The trailing backslash causes the next line to be 'spliced' to the line that ends inthe backslash - even if it's part of a comment.  This is nearly always unintentional (unless it's a deliberate obfuscation trick), and will cause a bug unless the next line is entirely whitespace or a comment itself.

This happens because 'line-splicing' occurs in translation phase 2, while removing comments happens in phase 3.

Newer compilers will warn about the single-line comment being continued to the next line (I'm not sure exactly what warning level might be required though):

- GCC 4.5.1 (MinGW)

  ```
  C:\temp\test.c:4:34: warning: multi-line comment
  ```
- MSVC 9 (VS 2008) or 10 (VS 2010):

  ```
  C:\temp\test.c(5) : warning C4010: single-line comment contains line-continuation character
  ```

Answer (score -1):

C:\temp\test.c:4:34: warning: multi-line comment

C:\temp\test.c(5) : warning C4010: single-line comment contains line-continuation character

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).